# SwiftUI: How to center map to users current location?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, gps, location

I'm using MapKit in SwiftUI to display a map with the current location of the user. I have this code so far, but the problem is that I have to manually specify the region.

**So my question is, How can I make the map always center around the current location of the user?**

I'm not that experienced yet, so I hope you will have some patience with me

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        Home()
    }
}


struct Home: View{

    @State var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.785834, longitude: -122.406417), latitudinalMeters: 1, longitudinalMeters: 1)

    @State var tracking : MapUserTrackingMode = .follow

    @State var manager = CLLocationManager()

    @StateObject var managerDelegate = locationDelegate()

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
//            Map(coordinateRegion: $region, interactionModes: .all, showsUserLocation: true, userTrackingMode: $tracking)
            
            Map(coordinateRegion: $region, interactionModes: .all, showsUserLocation: true, userTrackingMode: $tracking, annotationItems: managerDelegate.pins) { pin in
                MapPin(coordinate: pin.location.coordinate, tint: .red)
                
            }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }.onAppear{
            manager.delegate = managerDelegate
        }
    }
}

class locationDelegate: NSObject,ObservableObject,CLLocationManagerDelegate{
      
    @Published var pins : [Pin] = []

    // Checking authorization status...
  
    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {

        if manager.authorizationStatus == .authorizedWhenInUse{
            print("Authorized")
            manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        } else {
            print("not authorized")
            manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        pins.append(Pin(location:locations.last!))
    }
}

// Map pins for update
struct Pin : Identifiable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var location : CLLocation
}
```

**EDIT:**
I managed to center the map around the current location of the user. But I'm not sure my code is optimal, would appreciate it if you could take a quick look at it.

A problem I'm having with the new code is that when the user is moving, meaning if I set the simulator to simulate someone running or driving a car, I'm not able to zoom in or out or move the map at all. It keeps readjusting itself. Any ideas?

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit
import CoreLocation


struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        Home()
    }
}


struct Home: View{
    
    @State var tracking : MapUserTrackingMode = .follow

    @State var manager = CLLocationManager()

    @StateObject var managerDelegate = locationDelegate()

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
//            Map(coordinateRegion: $region, interactionModes: .all, showsUserLocation: true, userTrackingMode: $tracking)
            
            Map(coordinateRegion: $managerDelegate.region, interactionModes: .all, showsUserLocation: true, userTrackingMode: $tracking, annotationItems: managerDelegate.pins) { pin in
                MapPin(coordinate: pin.location.coordinate, tint: .red)
                
            }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }.onAppear{
            manager.delegate = managerDelegate
        }
    }
}

class locationDelegate: NSObject,ObservableObject,CLLocationManagerDelegate{
    @Published var pins : [Pin] = []
    
    // From here and down is new
    @Published var location: CLLocation?
    
    @State var hasSetRegion = false
    
    @Published var region = MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.898150, longitude: -77.034340),
        span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 1, longitudeDelta: 1)
    )
    
    
    // Checking authorization status...
  
    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {

        if manager.authorizationStatus == .authorizedWhenInUse{
            print("Authorized")
            manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        } else {
            print("not authorized")
            manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
    }

    
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        // pins.append(Pin(location:locations.last!))

        // From here and down is new
        if let location = locations.last {
            
            self.location = location

            if hasSetRegion == false{
                region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location.coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.001, longitudeDelta: 0.001))
                hasSetRegion = true
            }
        }
    }
}




// Map pins for update
struct Pin : Identifiable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var location : CLLocation
}
```

Comment: You would have to watch for updates from the `CLLocationManager` and update your `region` based on the location. My answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66411954/560942 would do this if you don't do the `if !hasSetRegion` check.

Comment: I looked at your answer, and i adopted some of it into my own code. But I'm not sure if the code I'm using is optimal. And a new problem has emerged. I have updated my post, would appreciate it if you took a look at it. @jnpdx

Comment: If you found it helpful, feel free to upvote the answer. In terms of zooming, you have to keep track of the zoom level and reflect it whenever the region is recentered.

Comment: Im not sure i understand, could you explain it a bit further or show me? @jnpdx

Comment: See the `span:` parameter? You'd have to keep track of that and change it dynamically based on the zoom level rather than setting it statically like I am.

Comment: But how come I can zoom in and out and move the map perfectly fine, when I'm working with a stationary location? @jnpdx

Comment: And how would I change it dynamically?

Comment: You can zoom in and out when stationary because the location manager callback that resets the region isn't getting called when the location isn't moving.

Comment: Okay, but if i somehow manage to dynamically change the span, isn't that just the zoom? How would I go about moving the map, meaning to the left or up or down. Because when I try to do so, it just resets? @jnpdx

Comment: Nick. Yes, the span is the zoom. I don't have time to sit down and write a full solution right now.